# Make a loop iteration wait for the repaint() method to complete

Tags: java, swing, awt, paintcomponent, repaint

After searching for an answer lots of threads about similar issues, I still don't find a solution that fits my needs.

Basically, I have a while loop and I'd like to wait for the repaint() method to complete before another iteration of that loop starts.

In more detail, I have some segments that are drawn in the paintComponent method of a *MapPanel* class that extends *JComponent*.
Then, when the user clicks on a button, an algorithm starts searching for intersections beginning with the "upper" segments (using endpoints as event points).
This algorithm is basically the while loop I spoke about, it calls another algorithm in this while loop sending one event point at each iteration (those event points are sent in order, from top to bottom).

What I'd like to do is to show the current "position" of the algorithm by drawing a line at the current event point.
As the algorithm finds new intersections, I'd like to show them too.
I did draw what was needed in the paintComponent() method.

The problem is that when I call the repaint() method for the MapPanel inside the loop, it waits for the whole loop to end before the UI is updated(I've found a lot about why it does that but not about how to fix this in my particular case).

Okay, I'm done with the explanations, here's the actual algorithm :

```
private void findIntersection(ArrayList<Segment> segments){
    QTree Q=new QTree();
    for (Segment s : segments){
        Q.initialise(s);
    }
    TreeT T=new TreeT();
    while (Q.getRoot()!=null){
        Point p = Q.maxEventPoint(Q.getRoot());
        Q.delete(p.getX(), p.getY());
        mapPanel.setSweeplinePosition(p.getY());
        handleEventPoint(p, T, Q);
        mapPanel.repaint()
        //should wait here for repaint() to complete
    }
        System.out.println("all intersections found, found " + mapPanel.getIntersections().size());
}
```

Comment: Use a [timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) or [worker thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

Comment: in which thread do you run this method?

Comment: Please see edits to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your long-running code is likely being called on the Swing event thread an action which prevents the event thread from doing its actions including drawing the GUI.

The solution is likely similar to what you've found in your search, but we don't know why you cannot use it with your program, and that is to do the while loop in a SwingWorker background thread, to publish the interim results using the SwingWorker's publish/process method pair, and then to do your drawings with the interim data.

For more on this, please read [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

---

For example

```
private void findIntersection(final ArrayList<Segment> segments) {
  final SwingWorker<Void, Double> myWorker = new SwingWorker<Void, Double>() {

     @Override
     protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        QTree Q = new QTree();
        for (Segment s : segments) {
           Q.initialise(s);
        }
        TreeT T = new TreeT();
        while (Q.getRoot() != null) {
           Point p = Q.maxEventPoint(Q.getRoot());
           Q.delete(p.getX(), p.getY());
           publish(p.getY()); // push data to process method

           // take care that this method below does not
           // make Swing calls
           handleEventPoint(p, T, Q);
        }
        return null;
     }

     @Override
     protected void process(List<Double> chunks) {
        for (Double yValue : chunks) {
           // this is called on the EDT (Swing event dispatch thread)
           mapPanel.setSweeplinePosition(yValue);
           mapPanel.repaint();
        }
     }
  };
  myWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

     @Override
     public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        // get notified when Worker is done
        if (evt.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
           // TODO: any clean up code for when worker is done goes here
           try {
              myWorker.get(); // must call to trap exceptions that occur inside worker
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (ExecutionException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
     }
  });
  myWorker.execute(); // execute worker
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was in fact not exactly what I found (similar but could not get it to work).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with the method Thread.sleep(milliseconds)???
For example, I'm used to do something like this in my code:

```
     btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        pca.setIcon(new ImageIcon("icon.png"));
                        for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
                        try{Thread.sleep(700);} catch(InterruptedException er){} 
                        x+=20;
                        p.repaint();
                    }}
                }).start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I used a simple Thread.sleep() in the first place (and I am now using it inside the doInBackground() method) but the problem is that Thread.sleep() prevents the thread from executing anything and, as the repaint() execution doesn't get executed when the thread is busy or sleeping, there was no GUI refresh until the end of the algorithm.
That's why I needed something like the SwingWorker to make the algorithm wait for the repaint() execution.
From what I now (think I) understand, your example works because you are calling repaint() in your new Thread, not because you are using Thread.sleep() :p

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've noticed that there was no GUI refresh until the end of the algorithm, so I put repaint() in a Thread ;) As you see, I'm a beginner and I try to solve my problem with the knowledge I have... If there is a more correct solution, I'm ready to get it...